# Update Prometheus Host/Port in Docker

Tags: docker, salt-stack, prometheus

Question: **How can I change a Prometheus container's host address from the default `0.0.0.0:9090` to something like `192.168.1.234:9090`**?

Background: I am trying to get a Prometheus container to install and start in a production environment on a remote server. Since the server uses an IP other than Prometheus's default (0.0.0.0), I need to update the host address that the Prometheus container uses. If I don't, I can't sign-in to the UI and see any of the metrics. The IP of the remote server is provided by the user during the app's installation.

From what I understand from Prometheus's [config document](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/) and the output of `./prometheus -h`, the host address is immutable and therefore needs to be updated using the `--web.listen-address=` command-line flag. My problem is I don't know how to pass that flag to my Prometheus container; I can't simply run `./prometheus --web.listen-address="<remote-ip>:9090"` because that's not a Docker command. And I can't pass it to the `docker run ...` command because Docker doesn't recognize that flag.

Environment:

- Using SaltStack for config management
- I cannot use Docker Swarm (i.e. each container must use its own `Dockerfile`)

Comment: huh? if your are running prometheus in a container, why would the containerized prometheus need to know anything about the containers hosts public ips?

Comment: So it can send metrics to that public IP and the user can then sign-in to the Prometheus UI and see them. If the Prometheus container on a remote server is broadcasting its metrics to `0.0.0.0:9090` but it's IP is `192.168.1.234`, how could the user see the metrics? If they go to 0.0.0.0 in their browser, they'll just be sent to own computer's localhost address and not that of the Prometheus server. Or am I thinking about all this in the wrong way?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to change the containerized prometheus' listen address. The 0.0.0.0/0 is the anynet *inside* the container.
By default, it won't even be accessible from your hosts network, let alone any surrounding networks (like the Internet).
You can map it to a port on a hosts interface though. The command for that looks somewhat like this:

```
docker run --rm -p 8080:9090 prom/prometheus
```

which would expose the service at `127.0.0.1:8080` on your *host*

You can do that with a public (e.g. internet-facing) interface as well, although i'd generally advise against exposing containers like this, due to numerous operational implications, which are somewhat beyond the scope of this answer. You should at least consider a reverse-proxy setup, where the users are only allowed to talk to some heavy-duty webserver which then communicates with prometheus, instead of letting them access your backend directly, even if this is just a small development deployment.

For general considerations on productionizing container setups, i suggest [this](https://mapr.com/blog/containers-best-practices-for-running-in-production/).

Despite it's clickbaity title, [this](https://dzone.com/articles/docker-is-dead) is a useful read.

Comment: Thank you for the links and explanation. But mapping the listen address to a different port on the same host's local address doesn't make the UI accessible by anyone outside that host, does it (even if it is proxied)? The host/server I'm referring to is a minimal RedHat VM with no graphical environment, so wouldn't I still run into the problem of not being able to sign in to the Prometheus UI?

Comment: 1) its not technically the same host, 2) I wrote that you can do the mapping with a public interface as well, 3) what does the graphical interface of your operating system have to do with anything? Look, I don't want to discourage you from doing your thing, but it sounds like you should read up on how to operate Linux systems in general and on what docker is in particular. Again, no offense, but you might end up shooting yourself in the foot otherwise.